# How can I change surface palette colors?

Tags: c++, sdl

I have code which runs perfectly fine without these lines:

```
SDL_LockSurface(sdlSurface);
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->r = 255;
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->b = 0;
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->g = 0;
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->a = 255;
SDL_UnlockSurface(sdlSurface);
```

I'm trying to change the surface color to something else but it's not working. I want to do it with the palette struct, I don't want to use the mapRGBA functions or anything like that. I just want to access the color component directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        cout << "could not initialized SDL." << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    bool quit = false;
    const char progTitle[] = "SDLProject";
    SDL_Event *sdlEvent = new SDL_Event();
    SDL_Window *sdlWindow;
    SDL_Renderer *sdlRenderer;
    SDL_Texture *sdlTexture;

    int winWidth = 640;
    int winHeight = 480;

    SDL_Surface *sdlSurface;

    sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(progTitle,100,100,winWidth,winHeight,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sdlWindow,-1,0);
    sdlTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(sdlRenderer,SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,winWidth,winHeight);
    sdlSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,winWidth,winHeight,8,0,0,0,0);

    SDL_LockSurface(sdlSurface);
    sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->r = 255;
    sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->b = 0;
    sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->g = 0;
    sdlSurface->format->palette->colors->a = 255;
    SDL_UnlockSurface(sdlSurface);

    SDL_UpdateTexture(sdlTexture,NULL,sdlSurface->pixels,sdlSurface->pitch);

    SDL_RenderClear(sdlRenderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(sdlRenderer, sdlTexture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);
    while(!quit) {
        SDL_PollEvent(sdlEvent);



        switch (sdlEvent->type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    delete sdlSurface;
    SDL_DestroyTexture(sdlTexture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(sdlRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(sdlWindow);
    SDL_Quit();

    cout << "program finished with zero errors." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So I have changed my code to this, but the output is still the same... I get a black screen. And as for the setPaletteColor function, it's supposed to return 0 if it's successful but I don't get any errors in the command line.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {
        cout << "could not initialized SDL." << endl;
        cout << "\tError: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    bool quit = false;
    const char progTitle[] = "SDLProject";
    SDL_Event *sdlEvent = new SDL_Event();
    SDL_Window *sdlWindow;
    SDL_Renderer *sdlRenderer;
    SDL_Texture *sdlTexture;

    int winWidth = 640;
    int winHeight = 480;

    SDL_Surface *sdlSurface;

    SDL_Color sdlColor;
    sdlColor.r = 255;
    sdlColor.g = 0;
    sdlColor.b = 255;
    sdlColor.a = 255;

    sdlWindow = SDL_CreateWindow(progTitle,100,100,winWidth,winHeight,SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(sdlWindow,-1,0);
    sdlSurface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(0,winWidth,winHeight,8,0,0,0,0);

    SDL_LockSurface(sdlSurface);
    if(!SDL_SetPaletteColors(sdlSurface->format->palette,&sdlColor,0,sdlSurface->format->palette->ncolors-1)) {
        cout << "palette was not able to be set." << endl;
        cout << "\tError: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    }
    SDL_UnlockSurface(sdlSurface);

    sdlTexture = SDL_CreateTexture(sdlRenderer,sdlSurface->format->format,SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,winWidth,winHeight);
    SDL_UpdateTexture(sdlTexture,NULL,sdlSurface->pixels,sdlSurface->pitch);

    SDL_RenderClear(sdlRenderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(sdlRenderer, sdlTexture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);

    while(!quit) {
        SDL_PollEvent(sdlEvent);



        switch (sdlEvent->type) {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
        }
    }

    delete sdlSurface;
    SDL_DestroyTexture(sdlTexture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(sdlRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(sdlWindow);
    SDL_Quit();

    cout << "program has ended." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A SDL_Palette consist of an Array of SDL_Color*, so you must provide the index of the color you're trying to modify.

```
int number_of_palette_entries = sdlSurface->format->palette->ncolors;
```

so you should do a range check before doing something like this :

```
// change index to pure Red
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors[index].r = 255;
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors[index].g = 0;
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors[index].b = 0;
sdlSurface->format->palette->colors[index].a = 255;
```

It is recommend however that you use the built in function to change palette colors

[SDL_SetPaletteColors](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetPaletteColors)

And some more example code for getting a color at the top-left pixel @

[SDL_PixelFormat (See example code)](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PixelFormat)